# Interactive Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So what I am trying to achieve is an interative `iframe`. This `iframe` will coincide with the current parent url(http://parenturl.com).

So say I have an `iframe` that goes to http://www.google.com and I click a link within said iframe.

This updates the parent url to http://parenturl.com#www.google.com/link2, the `iframe` then goes to what you clicked on.

I also would also like the parent url to accept parameters so if I do http://parenturl.com#bing.com it would go to http://bing.com.

Iframe code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" id="myFrame"></iframe>
```

Call on every click within iframe:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    window.top.location.href = "http://www.parenturl.com#"+$(this).attr('href'); 
});
```

Call when page is loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
var loc = 'Get url from # in parent url;
    document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', loc);
});
```

I have access to both domains, but I can only edit html on one.

Comment: Google wants nothing to do with iframes.

Comment: Just example urls

Comment: You can't edit the child page, so it's CORS allows parent's pages location to access it? I'm having a hard time trying to figure out that one can be edited while the other page you can't edit.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent cross site scripting attacks all communication from the iframe to the parent is not allowed when the iframe is on a different domain than the parent. You can set the iframe url from the parent. The other way - as in communicating the current url from iframe to parent - is not possible.

Comment: Well, technically of course, you can communicate across frames using [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) (and the proper CORS headers, etc.) but it requires the framed content to know what messages to post.

Comment: Can you help me a little more with this?